# Testdriven.net NCover integration: Excluding methods from Coverage Reports

Tags: .net, ncover, testdriven.net

I am using Testdriven.net to run NCover on my assemblies. However, I need to exclude certain methods from the coverage report. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by declaring an Attribute named `CoverageExcludeAttribute` in the global (sometimes referred to as the empty) namespace and applying this Attribute on the methods you want excluded from NCover.

NCover will pick up this attribute by its name only, so there's no need to reference any external assemblies. See also this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2006/11/11/Testing-With-NCover_2F00_NCoverExplorer.aspx). (It doesn't mention that the `CoverageExcludeAttribute` must be defined in the global namespace).